# FirebaseRecyclerView data is not showing using FirebaseUI, I get an error saying No Adapter Attached

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

**Can anyone check my code and tell is what I did wrong, as I am not able to show the data in RecyclerView**

*HomeFragment.class*

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

FirebaseAuth mAuth;

DatabaseReference databaseItemListView;

//ItemListView
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ItemListProduct> options;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView itemListView;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    databaseItemListView= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    InitializedValue(v);

    ValueEventListener firebaseList = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String SellerFireAdd = ds.getKey();

                    String firebaseItemName = ds.child("item_NAME").getValue(String.class);
                    String firebaseItemDesc = ds.child("item_DESCRIPTION").getValue(String.class);
                    String firebaseItemPrice = ds.child("item_PRICE").getValue(String.class);
                    String firebaseItemRatting = ds.child("item_RATTING").getValue(String.class);
                    String firebaseItemDiscount = ds.child("item_DISCOUNT").getValue(String.class);
                    String firebaseItemImage = (/**databaseLocation**/ds.child("item_IMAGE").getValue(String.class));

                    Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: The value collected from the Server are :" + firebaseItemName + " " + firebaseItemDesc
                            + " " + firebaseItemDiscount + " " + firebaseItemImage + " " + firebaseItemPrice + " " + firebaseItemRatting + " " + SellerFireAdd);

                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    databaseItemListView.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(firebaseList);

    RecyclerViewItemList();

    if (adapter!=null){
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    return v;
}

private void RecyclerViewItemList() {

    String TYPE="RESTAURANT";
    options= new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemListProduct>().setQuery(databaseItemListView,ItemListProduct.class).build();
    adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerViewFoodItem(options,this.getActivity(),TYPE);
    adapter.onDataChanged();
    itemListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
    itemListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (adapter!=null){
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

And this is my *FirebaseRecyclerViewFoodItem.class*

```
public class FirebaseRecyclerViewFoodItem extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ItemListProduct, FirebaseRecyclerViewFoodItem.FirebaseAdapter>{

private Activity context;
String TYPE;

/**
 * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
 * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
 *
 * @param options
 * @param context
 */
public FirebaseRecyclerViewFoodItem(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ItemListProduct> options, Activity context, String TYPE) {
    super(options);
    this.context = context;
    this.TYPE= TYPE;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public FirebaseRecyclerViewFoodItem.FirebaseAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card_view,
            parent, false);

    return new FirebaseRecyclerViewFoodItem.FirebaseAdapter(v);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerViewFoodItem.FirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter, final int i, @NonNull ItemListProduct itemListProduct) {

    Glide.with(context).load(itemListProduct.getITEM_IMAGE()).error(R.drawable.googleg_standard_color_18)
            .into(firebaseAdapter.itemImage);
    firebaseAdapter.itemName.setText(String.valueOf(itemListProduct.getITEM_NAME()));
    firebaseAdapter.itemDescription.setText(String.valueOf(itemListProduct.getITEM_DESCRIPTION()));
    firebaseAdapter.itemPrice.setText("₹ " + itemListProduct.getITEM_PRICE());
    firebaseAdapter.itemPrepareTime.setText(String.valueOf(itemListProduct.getITEM_PREPARATION_TIME()));

    String DiscountValue= String.valueOf(itemListProduct.getITEM_DISCOUNT());

    if (!DiscountValue.equals("null")){
        firebaseAdapter.itemDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(itemListProduct.getITEM_DISCOUNT()));
        firebaseAdapter.itemDiscount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        firebaseAdapter.itemDiscount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    String RattingValue= String.valueOf(itemListProduct.getITEM_RATTING());

    if (!RattingValue.equals("null")){
        firebaseAdapter.itemRatting.setText(String.valueOf(itemListProduct.getITEM_RATTING()));
        firebaseAdapter.itemRatting.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        firebaseAdapter.ImageViewRattingStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        firebaseAdapter.itemRatting.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        firebaseAdapter.ImageViewRattingStar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    firebaseAdapter.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Item_Details = getRef(i).getKey();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RestaurantDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("ITEM_NAME", Item_Details);
            context.startActivities(new Intent[]{intent});

        }
    });


}

public class FirebaseAdapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView ImageViewRattingStar, itemImage;
    TextView itemName, itemPrepareTime,itemDiscount,itemRatting,itemDescription, itemPrice;

    public FirebaseAdapter(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemDescription= itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewItemDescriptionAdapter);
        itemDiscount= itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewItemDiscountAdapter);
        itemImage= itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewItemImageViewAdapter);
        itemName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewItemNameAdapter);
        itemPrepareTime= itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewTimeForPreparation);
        itemPrice= itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewItemPriceAdapter);
        itemRatting= itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewItemRattingAdapter);
        ImageViewRattingStar= itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewRattingStar);

    }
}}
```

I am not able to find what is wrong in the code, earlier I was able to pull the **Data** but later I was not able to get the **Data**

Here is my Database:
[image]

Comment: Hi, you didn't attach the returned list of your firebase to the recycler view adapter

Comment: @Zain you mean notifyDataSetChange();

Comment: can you tell in brief I am not able to get you???

Comment: You received some data using the `ValueEventListener`, but this data is standalone you didn't feed your ReyclerView adapter with any data returned by the Firebase

Comment: Okay. can you show me how will I do that?

Comment: @Zain I mean can you show me how can I fixed that?

Comment: Please give me sometime

Comment: You can create a Model class that has String fields with setters & getters of the Firebase elements (name it MyModel) you want to show on the RecyclerView like firebaseItemName, firebaseItemDesc ..etc.. then in your activity create a List<MyModel> then in the `ValueEventListener` callback, inside the for loop, call MyModel model = snapshot.getValue(MyModel.class); and use the setters for ext model.setName(..) to set the model with the different values... and populate the List with these instances; then finally give this list to the RecyclerView adapter as a constructor argument

Comment: So, I have to create a setter and getter for the ValueEventListner, but I have one which is ItemListProduct. @Zain can you also please check my second class, where I have attached that line. Please!! I am getting all mixed up.

Comment: I am sorry but it didn't help,

Comment: @Zain maybe I did it wrong but frankly, I am not able to get you. Can you please write the code???